# Use a GLSL shader built in a sandbox with my WebGL code

Tags: heroku, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm very new to shaders and have modified a shader on glsl.heroku.com to suit my needs, see it here - this is what I want my 3D Object to look like: [Demo](http://glsl.heroku.com/e#12942.0). Now my question is how do I import it into my project using native webgl ([View my broken code here](http://webgl.scrivvy.co.uk/arc_light.html)). The shader code is as follows:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 surfacePosition;

void main( void ) {

float intensity = 3.0; // Lower number = more 'glow'
vec3 light_color = vec3(0.4, 0.3, 0.1); // RGB, proportional values, higher increases intensity
float master_scale = 0.01; // Change the size of the effect

float c = master_scale/(length(surfacePosition) * length(surfacePosition));
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(pow(c, intensity))*light_color, 1.0);

}
```

That's the fragment shader, so how do I build the correct vertex shader to go with it and pass through the surfacePosition variable (and what is the surface position variable???) using my broken code in the link above.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the source?

Comment: I've had a look but I don't fully understand where the surfacePosAttrib (which is being passed to the vertex shader through to the fragment shader) is coming from. All the tutorials I've tried don't really explain this subject very well in the WebGL context.

Comment: I've updated my code now and just get white shapes which is nothing like the demo

Comment: That's because you need to pass the attributes as well.

Comment: In the source code on Heroku there is a surface object, I don't have this object in my source code and can't work out where it's supposed to come from - any hints how I can get access to this data that I'm supposed to provide to the shader?

`surface.positionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "surfacePosAttrib");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(surface.positionAttribute);`

Comment: The code itself should give you the answer.

Comment: I've been staring at it for 3 hours, getting nowhere. It's a lot to take in on your first day of learning...

Comment: Well, then stop and start again tomorrow. Instead of just copy and pasting, why not actually researching what all that stuff is. Last but not least, again we are not here to teach you how everything works, your suppose to do all that research yourself!

Comment: I have been using the tutorials on learningwebgl.com, not just copy pasting, I wrote every line manually myself and read all the text accompanying the code... If you know of any resources that explain it better then please point me to them as this is a steep learning curve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the source I'm going to guess `surfacePosition` is just the vertex position * some matrix.

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
varying vec2 surfacePosition;
uniform mat4 mat;

void main() {
  gl_Position = a_position;
  surfacePosition = (a_position * mat).xy;
}
```

setup

```
var verts = [
    1,  1,  
   -1,  1,  
   -1, -1,  
    1,  1,  
   -1, -1,  
    1, -1,  
];
var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

...

```
var loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "mat");
var mat = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
];
mat[5] = canvas.height/canvas.width;  
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, mat);    

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

The matrix lets you adjust the rendering aspect based on the size of the canvas as well as implement pan and zoom. [See this article](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html).

here's a snippet

```js
var countElem = document.getElementById("t");
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, ["vshader", "fshader"], ["a_position"]);
gl.useProgram(program);

var verts = [
      1,  1,  
     -1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1, -1,  
];
var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

var loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "mat");
var mat = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
];
// index 0 = x scale  (ie, aspect & zoom)
// index 5 = y scale  (ie, aspect & zoom)
// index 12 = x offset (pan x)
// index 13 = y offset (pan y)
mat[5] = canvas.height/canvas.width;  
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, mat);    


gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<script id="vshader" type="whatever">
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    varying vec2 surfacePosition;
    uniform mat4 mat;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
      surfacePosition = (a_position * mat).xy;
    }    
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="whatever">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 surfacePosition;
void main() {
float intensity = 3.0; // Lower number = more 'glow'
vec3 light_color = vec3(0.4, 0.3, 0.1); // RGB, proportional values, higher increases intensity
float master_scale = 0.01; // Change the size of the effect

float c = master_scale/(length(surfacePosition) * length(surfacePosition));
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(pow(c, intensity))*light_color, 1.0);
}
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Very helpful answer, it's clearer now that all the 'extra' code is removed and I can research the bits I don't understand - Thanks!